# sql server trigger updates only one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a trigger after update an I want to update not only one row by one update, but also more rows. But when I try to update more rows, error *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.* appears. Is there a way to update more rows?

```
ALTER TRIGGER ChangeActorWhileUpdate
ON Herec
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @od DATE;
DECLARE @idHerce INT;


SELECT @idHerce = (SELECT id_herce FROM DELETED);


IF EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM historie_hercu WHERE Herec_id_herce = @idHerce)
BEGIN

    SELECT @od = (SELECT MAX(do) FROM historie_hercu WHERE Herec_id_herce=@idHerce)

END

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM historie_hercu WHERE Herec_id_herce = @idHerce) = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @od = (SELECT datum_narozeni FROM DELETED);
END

INSERT INTO historie_hercu (jmeno_herce, prijmeni_herce, datum_narozeni, datum_umrti, mesto_narozeni, mesto_umrti, zeme, od, do, Herec_id_herce) 
SELECT jmeno_herce, prijmeni_herce, datum_narozeni, datum_umrti, mesto_narozeni, mesto_umrti, zeme, @od, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), @idHerce FROM DELETED;

COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
ROLLBACK;
END CATCH 
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers are fired once for the batch of rows affected by the triggering action, they are not fired once for each row. You need to write your code in a way that it can handle more than 1 row.

Try something like.....

```
ALTER TRIGGER ChangeActorWhileUpdate
ON Herec
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
     BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

  WITH X AS (
    SELECT d.* , h.do AS H_Do 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.Herec_id_herce ORDER BY do DESC) rn
    FROM deleted d
    LEFT JOIN historie_hercu h ON d.id_herce = h.id_herce
    )
    INSERT INTO historie_hercu 
    (jmeno_herce, prijmeni_herce, datum_narozeni, datum_umrti
                     , mesto_narozeni, mesto_umrti, zeme, od, do, Herec_id_herce) 
    SELECT x.jmeno_herce, x.prijmeni_herce, x.datum_narozeni, x.datum_umrti
         , x.mesto_narozeni , x.mesto_umrti, x.zeme
         , ISNULL(x.H_Do ,x.datum_narozeni)  
         , CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), x.id_herce 
    FROM x
    WHERE x.rn = 1;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

END CATCH 
END
```

Comment: Now it does update as I want, but now for example if I want to update records from table _Herec_ with id between 12 and 15, it inserts into _historie_hercu_ record with id 15, and when i do same update again, it inserts records with ids 14 and 15 etc. This not happens if I do update like `UPDATE herec SET prijmeni_herce = 'Norris' WHERE id_herce=6 OR id_herce=22;` ...why?

Comment: @mates.lukas94: If this solution answers to your question then please choose / mark as [Solution]. This is not a forum.

Comment: SQL Server triggers are executed in the context of transaction. We don't have to open another transaction within trigger. To test this assumption, I would add `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS TxCount` at the beginning of trigger source code.